# Spring JPA - @OneToMany create separate tables per relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I want to create type called

```
@Entity
class TestType {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String field1;
   private String field2;
}

@Entity
class Agregator{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   @OneToMany
   private List<TestType> newTypes;
   @OneToMany
   private List<TestType> oldTypes;
}
```

and I want to have 3 tables:

- agregator
- agregator_new_types with column agregator_id;
- agregator_old_types with column agregator_id;

How I need to define relation to get such tables and columns ?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Embeddable
class TestType {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String field1;
   private String field2;
}

@Entity
class Agregator{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   @ElementCollection
   private List<TestType> newTypes;
   @ElementCollection
   private List<TestType> oldTypes;
}
```